# When I request anything on postman return an error of property is undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I request anything in Postman, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'itemService')
>
> at /home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/src/controllers/Item.ts:11:34
> at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
> at /home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/src/controllers/Item.ts:8:71
> at new Promise (<anonymous>)
> at __awaiter (/home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/src/controllers/Item.ts:4:12)
> at getAll (/home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/src/controllers/Item.ts:21:16)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next (/home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
> at Route.dispatch (/home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/monts/projects/MarysPizzaTS/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

This is the controller responsible for handling HTTP requests related to items. It defines an ItemController class with methods for retrieving all items (getAll). In the constructor, an instance of the ItemService class is injected to handle the business logic:

```js
//ItemController

import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import ItemService from '../services/Item';

class ItemController {
    private itemService: ItemService;

    constructor(itemService: ItemService) {
        this.itemService = new ItemService();
    }
    async getAll(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const items = await this.itemService.getAll();
        res.status(200).json(items);
    }
}

export default ItemController;
```

Comment: try to change the constructor to : `constructor(itemService: ItemService) {
    this.itemService = itemService;
  }`

Comment: keeps giving the same error

Comment: the link of github repo [github](https://github.com/montemurro19/MarysPizzaTS)

Comment: You are calling `getAll` incorrectly. You lost `this` reference

Comment: where did i forget to put the 'this'? I didn't understand, I was trying to get the property getAll from the ItemService class

Comment: Show how you call `ItemController.getAll`

Comment: const router = Router();
const itemService = new ItemService();
const itemController = new ItemController(itemService);

router.get('/', itemController.getAll);

Comment: `router.get('/', (req, res) => itemController.getAll(req, res));` or `router.get('/', itemController.getAll.bind(itemController));`